# Textfield Input Validation in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, validation

I have to put validation on a `UITextField` for user input.

The user must input into the textfield a value

**i.e. 70-80 or 85 mean num-num or num**

Right now, I just allow to user to input only digits& `-` but drawback is that user can also input `-` number of times.

```
// My code is as follow

NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789-"] invertedSet];

    if (([txtMarks.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound )||[txtMarks.text isEqualToString:@""] ) {

        UIAlertView *alt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Invalid Input" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alt show];
        [alt release];
    }
```

Comment: you want to allow user to add values like this 70-80 or 85.Can user enter like this 34-35-38?

Comment: No, Only num-num or num.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply Try this,

```
    int times = [[txtMarks.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] count]-1;
    if(times>1)
    {
        UIAlertView *alt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"'-' used more than one" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alt show];
        [alt release];    
    }
```

**EDIT 1**

Using `NSPredicate` we can do it. Try this,

```
    NSString *regex = @"[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?";
    NSPredicate *testRegex = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];

    if([testRegex evaluateWithObject:textField.text])
        NSLog(@"Match");
    else
        NSLog(@"Do not match");
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: it allow user to input `-`at first

Answer (score 1):

Try it using the following regular expression, It restricts user to enter more than one `-`.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    NSString *expression = @"^([0-9]{1,}+)?(\\-([0-9]{1,})?)?$";

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                             error:&error];
    NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:newString
                                                        options:0
                                                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [newString length])];
    if (numberOfMatches == 0)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Why downvote what wrong in this code. I had written same code & works as per the question.

Comment: i didn't down vote to you man! Any one else did it. I am trying your code. & also Thanks for your reply..

Comment: Write the above code in shouldChangeCharactersInRange method, which allows user while entering the second -.

Comment: You are missing a `return` statement. Also, shouldn't the `if` statement be `if (numberOfMatches != 1)`?

Comment: @Girish There are some problems like it allows to input `-`at first & when i try to write 80-90 then it only allow 80-9

Comment: @Girish, I am facing the same problem as earlier.

Comment: check now, I had set the min - max char limit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this first find whether your string contains `-`

Here subtring is `-`

```
if ([txtMarks.text hasPrefix:@"-"]||[txtMarks.text hasSuffix:@"-"])
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"sorry " message:@"invalid inoput as it has - at start or end" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
else
{
  NSRange textRange;
  textRange =[string rangeOfString:substring];

  if(textRange.location == NSNotFound)
  {
      //Does not  contain the substring
     NSlog(@" string contains only num")

  }
  else
  {
     int times = [[txtMarks.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] count];
     if(times==2)
     {
         Nslog(@"num-num input")

     }
     else
    {
       UIAlertView *alt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"'-' used more than one" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
         [alt show];
         [alt release];    
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. but it never goes into num-num input

Comment: but with this user can also do input `-` at first character

Comment: chk it now now it will give alert if user enters "-" either as a first or last character

Comment: Greate Coding..!! Thanks a lot... But sorry to say i alredy accept the answer so i just give upvote to your answer.

Comment: ur Wc, no issues you always chose the best answer so that it can help someone in future.